# Proving $t^2 e^{t} - 2 t e^{t} + 2 e^{t} - 2 \geq 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How to prove the following inequality for $t \geq 0$
$$
t^2 e^{t} - 2 t e^{t} + 2 e^{t} - 2 \geq 0
$$

I tried to prove it using this inequality $\ln a ≤ a − 1$ for any $a >0$ from this reference [1] but I cannot.

[1] R. W. Yeung, Information theory and network coding. Springer Science &Business Media, 2008

Comment: It's not true if you allow $a x < 0$.  Hint: write the left side as a function of $t = ax$ and consider the derivative of that function.

Comment: Please don't change the question after receiving comments and answers, without acknowledging them.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $$f(t)=t^2 e^{t} - 2 t e^{t} + 2 e^{t} - 2 $$ for which $f(0)=0$.

What is interesting is that
$$f'(t)=t^2 e^{t}$$ is always positive. So ???

Answer (score 0):

let $f(t)=t^2-2t+2-2e^{-t}$
$f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=0$
$f'''(t)=2e^{-t}\geq 0$
so $f(t)\geq 0$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you try to use the second-order Taylor approximation but you can not use an approximation to prove an inequality. How do you make sure that the approximation is always larger than the exact value?

Answer (score 0):

A simple proof that avoids calculus.
To prove that $f(t) =e^t(t^2+2t+2) \geq 2$

We know that for $t\geq 0$, $e^t \geq 1+t $
$$\implies f(t) \geq (1+t)(t^2+2t+2)=(1+t) \Big((1+t)^2 +1\Big)$$
$$ \implies f(t) \geq (1+t)^3+(1+t)$$
For $t\geq 0$, the RHS is greater than 2. Hence proved.

Comment: May I ask why $e^t \geq 1 + t$ ? the first-order Taylor approximation $e^t \approx  1 + t$ is an approximation does not imply the value is greater or smaller than the value of the function.

Comment: One way to prove it is to use the limiting case of the Bernoulli's inequality.
Even with the Taylor series however, $1+t$ is merely the first order truncation, which is  lesser than $e^t$ because the other terms are positive.